# How to make ngRoute ignore a url

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I am using ngRoute in AngularJs. I want to configure it to ignore some urls like /#A1. To be more specific, I dont want it to load anything in the page. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean dont want it to load anything in the page?

Comment: `href="" target="_self"` did you try this in your `<a>` tag

Comment: I have an owl carousel in the webpage, which has the URLHashListener option enabled. This means that, based on the url, the carousel scrolls to the desired location. The url is something like:
    <base-url>/#A1
So, I dont want ngRoute to act on this url, but leave it to the owl carousel

Comment: Yes Divya MV, I tried that this way
<a href="#A1" target="_self">link</a>
but, the problem is that the current page's partial is reloading, which I dont want to happen